# Mounting the ur5e robotic arm on a table

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, motion-planning, gazebo, rviz

I am working on testing motion planning algorithms on a robotic arm. My arm collides with the ground while moving it from one point to another point. My solution to this problem is to mount the arm on a table. How do I do that? And is there a better solution to the problem?
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to attach the physical arm to a table, or the simulated arm in gazebo?

Comment: @Ben On the simulated arm in gazebo

Comment: you need to modify the urdf file. Add a link with fixed joint between the table and the base of ur5.